# Network printer makes noise every time I insert/remove a USB device

Tags: networking, usb, printing

I know that I've encountered an answer to this question before, but I can't seem to figure out the right search terms to find the answer anywhere.

I have an Epson WF4630 at my office and an Epson 845 printer at home. Both are on wired networks.

Every time I log into any Ubuntu system or VM (12.04, 14.04, 14.10) on the local network, and most times I insert or remove a USB device (flash drive, webcam, fpga board... anything) my network printer 'spools'—it sounds like clearing the paper path and then moving and re-homing the print head.

Wireshark confirms stuff happens: every time I plug or unplug a usb device, i see BJNP and MDNS traffic broadcast, and then a TCP connection to the printer.

So the question is: what causes that to happen, and how can I disable it?

Comment: Can you post the relevant captured packets to http://paste.ubuntu.com?

Comment: I have been experiencing this with an Epson WF-7525 when inserting or removing USB devices from my Ubuntu 15.10 machine. It also occurs when booting my machine or resuming it from standby. For posterity, [I had asked the question on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/981187/epson-wf-7525-makes-noise-when-plugging-in-usb-device), which now points back here.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem with an Epson network printer. To find out what was causing it, I used [`netstat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/netstat.html) to monitor the network connections while inserting a USB device:

```
sudo netstat -t -u -a -p -c
```

One connection appeared a few moments after the device was inserted: a UDP connection by `colord-sane`. This binary is part of [`colord`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/colord), a "system service to manage device colour profiles".

Unfortunately, disabling this service (at least on 15.04) is more difficult than it would seem. `colord` is not started directly by the init system `systemd`. Instead, `dbus` starts `colord`, or is asked to start `colord` by some other service (at least not the printer service [`cupsd`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cups)). One way to prevent this is by renaming the relevant service file:

```
cd /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/
sudo mv org.freedesktop.ColorManager.service org.freedesktop.ColorManager.service.disabled
```

I don't know what side-effects this action might have. Another possibility is to uninstall `colord` completely, using

```
sudo apt-get remove colord
```

As I don't really need colour profile functionality on my Ubuntu device, I didn't investigate what exactly `colord` does to "activate" the printer, or how to teach it not to do so.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was very insightful! `colord` was also the culprit for me, and I decided to bite the bullet and remove it from my machine as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it now seems that removing `colord` will also remove the`gnome-control-center` in Ubuntu 20.04 at least, which is the main settings interface. Dang.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved for my Epson WF3520 without breaking colord, which seems deeply integrated into most linux systems.

**Comment out**

> **net autodiscovery**

in **/etc/sane.d/epson2.conf** and **/etc/sane.d/epsonds.conf** (with a # at the start of the line)

This may be applicable to other printers through their .conf files as well ("kodakaio"/"magicolor"?)

Credits go to: [Link1](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104465#c1) / [Link2](https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends/-/issues/130#note_220272507)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my Epson WF-3640.  I have a desktop and a laptop both running Ubuntu 20.04 and every time they start up they both trigger the spool/cycle on the printer.  It only lasts about 3 seconds but it got very annoying.

```
sudo apt-get remove colord
```

The above answer worked for me (thanks) but then I couldn't access settings.  I found these three lines of code which you can run after uninstalling colord.  I hope the developer fixes this problem.

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-control-center
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```